# Jasper file not found when build with maven, working fine in eclipse

Tags: maven, jasper-reports, file-not-found

the prob im facing is, when Im running my project in eclipse its able to find my jasper file and showing the report but when im making jar of my project and running it, its not able to find my jasper file and throwing FileNotFoundException..

Path Im using :"jasperReport = "src\com\myproject\jasper\TestReportTamplate_V1.jasper";" -

I have attached My project structure image below:

[Project Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/130wD.jpg)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with jasper, it's a more general problem locating the files by their absolute path. When you create a jar, the folder structure is not the same. 'src' is not kept, as one example. Just open it like an archive with 7Z or something like that, and you can see.

Use relative paths when trying to locate files in the code. For example, if you are in the controller package, it should be something like "../jasper/TestReportTamplate_V1.jasper" ('..' represents the parent folder, '.' represents the current folder - go from there).

Comment: Sorry to say, but I read and get to know that '.' and '..' work in file system(in eclipse) but when its exported in jar, jar wont have the file system structure. so it wont work.